# Is there a .NET alternative to Java's RedDwarf networking solution?

Tags: c#, .net, p2p

I can see that there are namespaces in System.net dedicated to p2p functionality, (http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms734699(v=VS.85).aspx) is this comparable featurewise to other solutions made possible by RedDwarf, red5, or Flash Media Server? Basically, I want highspeed realtime online gaming, video and messaging without putting too much strain on the server. (isn't that what everyone wants ;)) 
The obvious solution to me would be p2p technology, but I can't find any competitive solution with .NET. The barebones namespaces seem to exist though, but googling doesn't result in any anecdotal evidence that these services are actually fast enough for realtime gaming and video.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching google for '.NET p2p framework' yields a good number of results for how to use the built-in services like WCF, as well as a bunch of third party, open source, and commercial offerings.

http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=.net+p2p+framework